# i cant make a yesno while learning c

Tags: c

i am trying to learn c and i want to make a yesno with a single char. here is my code:

i have tried this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//just playing

int main()
{
    char yesno;
    printf("TEST [Y/n] ");
    scanf(" %c", &yesno);
    if(yesno == "y") {
        printf("You did yes!!");
    } else if(yesno == "n") {
        printf("You did no!");
    } else {
        printf("Not valid!!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it skips to else automatically
why is this

update: i did not know that this is a duplicate. idk what double quotes were and singles were before

Comment: To compare two strings in C you should use the `strcmp` function. Best of luck.

Comment: There is a difference between single quotes and double quotes. Single quotes specify a single character while double quotes specify a string. Your `yesno` is a single character, so you should be comparing it to `'y'` and `'n'`.

Answer (score 4):

Here

```
yesno == "y"
```

you are comparing a char `yesno` with string `"y"`. It should be

```
yesno == 'y'  /* use single quotation instead of double quotation */
```

Side note always compile your code with minimum below flags & don't ignore the warnings, work on those. For e.g

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpedantic -Werror test.c
```

where `Werror` converts warning into error & stops the compilation so that you shouldn't jump to the output & forces you to read & solve the compiler error message.

Comment: i cant accept your answer you answer for 4 minute. but it works... thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**Lesson learned :  Never ever ignore compiler warnings.**

use 'y' instead of "y"

This will work :) Happy learnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//just playing

int main()
{
    char yesno;
    printf("TEST [Y/n] ");
    scanf(" %c", &yesno);
    if(yesno == 'y') {
        printf("You did yes!!");
    } else if(yesno == 'n') {
        printf("You did no!");
    } else {
        printf("Not valid!!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```